# using jest to test react component and event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs

I'm totally new to jest and testing components

And I've been doing well without testing.

However I found desperate need for testing and I'm trying to make one.

Case :

I have two components named 'Audio','Pad' and wrapper component 'Layout'.

They works like this: if pad is clicked, audio plays sound when it received a prop (isAudible).

Here is Audio.jsx:

```
class Audio extends React.Component {

componentWillReceiveProps () {
    this.audio.play()
}

render () {
    return (
        <audio src={mp3s[0]} preload="auto" ref={ref => { this.audio = ref }}></audio>
    ) 
  }
}
```

and another one-pads which has 4 pads consists of style(styled-components):

```
class Pads extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Flexboard>
                <Pad onClick={this.props.onClick} color={colors.red} className="top-left" />
                <Pad onClick={this.props.onClick} color={colors.blue} className="top-right"/>
                <Pad onClick={this.props.onClick} color={colors.yellow} className="bottom-left"/>
                <Pad onClick={this.props.onClick} color={colors.green} className="bottom-right"/>
            </Flexboard>
        )
    }
}
```

finally my Layout component:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isAudible: false
        }
    }

    turnOn () {
        this.setState(prev => ({ isAudible: !prev.isAudible }))
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Pads onClick={ e => this.turnOn(e) } />
                <Audio isAudible={ this.state.isAudible }/>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I make some simple test that assures they work well as I expect:
'Audio plays when it received a prop named isAudible'?

I've executed this app and audio plays well so what I want to know is how to write component.test.js for this case.